# Does WABT provide complete support for WebAssembly Garbage Collection (WasmGC)?

Tags: compiler-construction, webassembly

I can see that *wat2wasm* does have the option to enable "gc" but when running this example (with all features enabled):

```
(module
  (type $Node (struct (field $next (ref null $Node)) (field $value (mut i32))))

  (global $global (mut (ref null $Node)) (ref.null $Node))

  (export "global" (global $global))

  (export "_start" (func $_start))

  (func $_start
    (local $i i32)
    (loop $loop
      (global.set $global
        (struct.new $Node
          (global.get $global)
          (local.get $i)
        )
      )
      (local.set $i
        (i32.add
          (local.get $i)
          (i32.const 1)
        )
      )
    
      (br_if $loop
        (i32.le_u
          (local.get $i)
          (i32.const 1000)
        )
      )
    )

  )
)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: parseWat failed:
test.wast:2:41: error: unexpected token "null", expected a numeric index or a name (e.g. 12 or $foo).
  (type $Node (struct (field $next (ref null $Node)) (field $value (mut i32))))
```

It does work in **[binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen) ***wasm-as*, but this does not help me since I am building a compiler that produces WAT programs written in the linear writing style. I rely on *wat2wasm* to produce binary executables and would like to take advantage of WasmGC.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in *wat2wasm* or if it will be supported soon?

Any suggestions are very welcome! :)

Comment: I have found that not even _function references_ work in wat2wasm yet, and GC spec builds upon that. But the same is for e.g. nodejs and webkit. Looks like only chrome and firefox support GC yet.